# Snowflake ODBC driver never pulls more than a million records

Tags: python, odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, pyodbc, alteryx

We are using the Snowflake ODBC Driver to connect to our warehouse from a series of different, completely unrelated backends.

We have Alteryx workflows and Python applications connecting to the warehouse through ODBC.

We can successfully establish a connection and access the information in our databases, however, there is a hard limit of 1000000 when selecting records from a table. It never pulls more than that. No error or warning messages either, it simply does not pull more than a million record, regardless of the source where we run the process from.

The applications and Alteryx run on completely different servers as well, so it's unlikely that it is a server issue.

I have not been able to find anything about this on the Snowflake documentation, and I'm at a lost as to where to search.

What's even more odd: We can upload more than a million records from Alteryx into Snowflake. The issue is just for when we receive the data FROM snowflake.

Any ideas on where/what to check?

Comment: Are you on the latest ODBC driver version?  Any clues from the application logs or the ODBC driver logs (link below to that)?  And is this regardless of table (if you query another table with over a million records)?  Also, if you run "select system$whitelist();" can you confirm all these endpoints are whitelisted across any security policies, proxies, firewalls, etc.? Your networking team can trace the traffic there as needed just to rule out a networking issue.  https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-generate-log-file-on-Snowflake-connectors

Comment: Are you sure parameter [**ROWS_PER_RESULTSET**](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#rows-per-resultset) is not set? There's no limitation on ODBC from the number of rows point of view by default.

Comment: Thank you Sergiu that was indeed the issue! All of our users had the ROWS_PER_RESULTSET parameter set to 1000000.
Can you please write your comment as an answer to select it as the correct one?